# solve x for $ \sin{x} - \cos{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = 0 $ (0 <= x < $2\pi$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I assume that $ \sin{x} - \cos{x} $ must have the value of $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $

instead of put x in one by one, how to get the expression of x = something, so we get x1 = a, x2 = b 

( that causes  $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $ 
) like solving quadratic equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin x-\cos x-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}=0$$

$$\sin x-\cos x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sin x-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cos x= \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\cos\frac{\pi}{4}\sin x-\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\cos x=\frac{1}{2}$$

Recall the identity

$$\sin A\cos B-\sin B\cos A=\sin(A-B) $$

$$\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$x-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

$$x=\frac{5\pi}{12}$$

Comment: The step where you drop the $\sin$ function is not valid--there are *infinitely many* values of $x-\frac{\pi}4$ that have a sine of $\frac 12$. The problem statement gives no limits on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x-\cos x=\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}\sin\left(x+\arctan\dfrac1{-1}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\ sinx - cosx = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2)} $

$\ (-\sqrt{2}) \cdot ((cosx)(cos\frac{\pi}{4}) - (cosx)(cos\frac{\pi}{4})) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $

See if you can figure it out from there given the identity:

$\ cos(a+b) = cosa \cdot cosb - sina \cdot sinb $

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite this as $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos x= \frac{1}{2}$ or (using trig identity for sine of difference): $$\sin(x-\pi/4)=0.5$$